Showing that an irreducible variety of degree $1$ is a linear subspace
I am a beginner in Algebraic Geometry, this is an exercise from my bachelor's course, which I'm stuck in.

If $X$ is an irreducible variety of degree $1$, then $X$ is a linear subspace.

I tried to do an induction over $d$, the dimension of $X$. If $d=0$ then $X$ is a point and that's easy. Assume the statement for all irreducibles varieties of dimension $d-1$ and prove for $X$ of dimension $d$. I tried to cut $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ with hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and use the inductive hypothesis but all I was able to say is that $X$ is union of linear subspaces, that is in general not a linear subspace.
I can't use higher tools like schemes, I 'm searching for a hint.
Thank you all

How do you define degree? What exactly is your definition of variety and linear subspace?

@ClemensB we defined a variety as the locus of zeros of a homogenous polynomials' set, a linear subspace is a variety where the equations are linear. The degree of a variety X
is the cardinality of X∩Y
where Y
is a linear subspace of dimension n−d

How many times does a line intersect the union of $r$ hyperplanes?

Please be more precise about the definition of degree: you cannot allow $Y$ to be any linear subspace of dimension $n - d$, otherwise if $X$ is a linear subspace it will not have a well-defined degree by taking eg $Y \subset X$ or $Y \supset X$ depending on $d > n -d$ or $d < n - d$. Do you know that this holds for an open set of $Y$ or all $Y$ such that $Y \cap X$ is finite or all $Y$ such that $Y \cap X$ is $0$-dimensional or ... ?
